# how to get the third friday for a month in c++?

Tags: c++, date

i think date handling is a little complex.

so, i want to know if there is any elegant algorithm that i can get any dates in my condition like the third friday's date in sep 2020?

let's specify two method i want:

```
int get_date(int month, int weekday, int no) {  // for example: get_date(202009, 3, 3)
     //  should return the third wednesday in sep 2020, it's 20200917
}

int date_sub(int date1, int date2) { // for example:
   // date_sub(20200928, 20200925) should return 3

}
```

i know boost have some nice things, but i think it may too heavy, is there any better choice?

Comment: What did you read about dates and calendars? Do you know about [date and time utilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) in C++ ? In 202009 the calendar will surely change (it changed both in Europe and in China a few centuries ago, and in Russia about a hundred years ago). For Linux, see also [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)...

Comment: Your convention of appending the month and day to the year to make a single number is unusual.  I doubt any standard code is going to support it.

Comment: Is the value 202009 a representation of 2020-09?  You'd probably do better separating the year from the month.  You ask about 3rd Friday; on most schemes, Friday is day 5 of the week (the only debate is whether Sunday is day 0 or day 7), so is your call trying to calculate the third Wednesday in September 2020?  What do you plan to do about the 5th Friday in the month when there are only 4 Fridays?  The normal rule is to return the 4th Friday as it is the last.

Comment: sorry for the bad description, i have add some information, hope it can be more clear

Comment: I know of no library using your representation of dates.  You could do the calculation by converting to `struct tm` and using `mktime()` and `gmtime()` or `localtime()` to create the value after you've fiddled with the fields.  It's not trivial, but it's not impossible.  Use midday rather than midnight to avoid issues with oddball changes between winter and summer (standard and daylight saving) time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is trivial using either the [c++20 date support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_weekday/accessors) or [Howard Hinnants implementation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
    constexpr year_month_day date {year(2020)/September/Friday[3]};
    std::cout << date;
}
```

or

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace date;

int main()
{
    constexpr year_month_day date {year(2020)/September/Friday[3]};
    std::cout << date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no compiler supports `std::chrono` [Calendar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono#Calendar:%7E:text=Calendar,-Defined) as of now, but they will catchup eventually, so, to be future-proof, here are the functions you asked for expressed using it:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>

std::chrono::sys_days get_date(std::chrono::year_month year_month, 
                               std::chrono::weekday weekday,
                               unsigned weekday_index) {
    return std::chrono::year_month_weekday {
        year_month.year(), year_month.month(), 
        std::chrono::weekday_indexed(weekday, weekday_index)
    }
}

std::chrono::duration<std::chrono::days> date_sub(std::chrono::sys_days lhs,
                                                  std::chrono::sys_days rhs) {
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::days>(lhs - rhs);
}

int main() {
    [[maybe_unused]] signed difference = date_sub(
        get_date(2020y / std::chrono::month::September, std::chrono::weekday::Friday, 3),
        get_date(2020y / std::chrono::month::September, std::chrono::weekday::Tuesday, 3)
    ).count();

    assert(difference == 3);
}
```